# Query information not populating in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Here is a link to the [doc](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xXdrIB2ILEoa7Jr2-xYThFqlDXB2HjVh_MTLTB78XD4/edit?usp=sharing)

On sheet two cell A6 there is a query:

```
=QUERY('Events Summary'!1:970, "SELECT A,F,BG,M,BA,BB,BC,BD,BF,BE 
 WHERE F = date'"&text(Today(),"YYYY-MM-dd")&"'order by M DESC ",1)
```

The information for columns A, F, & M populates but the rest do not. Is this because they are out of their natural order?

Answer (score 0):

it is empty because the source is empty:

[image]

Comment: Oh good gravy! Sorry to have bothered you.  Thanks for pointing it out for me.